# What is $\frac{d\left( (\cos(x))^{\cos(x)}\right)}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would you work something like this out?

Are there similar problems to
$$\frac{d\left( (\cos(x))^{\cos(x)}\right)}{dx}$$
which could be worked out the same way?

Comment: Does it even make sense when $\cos x$ is negative?

Comment: At $x = 135^\circ = \frac{3 \pi}{4}$, please try to find the value of $(\cos x)^{\cos x}$. Can you find it? Remember, even before you think of differentiation and what not, you must check well definition. Wherever well defined, one must check if the chain rule applies or not and use it carefully to find the derivative of the given function.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг why is $(-2)^{\sqrt 2}$ undefined?

Comment: @Gurjinder : Not undefined, just not a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ (or even $A\to\mathbb R$ with $A\subset\mathbb R$)

Comment: @Gurjinder The reason why I am apparently making a hue and cry about this, is the fact that one cannot blindly differentiate without taking into account the fact that this is not even a well defined function. Granted it is so if $\cos x > 0$, however, and in that case the chain rule works out fine. As a user below has pointed out, maybe I have been too harsh. I would like to apologize and add a $+1$ in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Given proper domain for the function so that $\cos(x) >0$ we can write:
$$(\cos x)^{\cos x} = e^{(\cos x) \ln(\cos x)}$$

Comment: Use that $\cos(x)^\cos(x)=e^{\cos(x)ln(\cos(x))}$

Answer (score 2):

The go-to way for the derivative of $f^g$ is $(f(x)^{g(x)})'=(e^{g(x)\ln f(x)})'$ and then use chain rule. Or knowing by heart the formula that follows directly from this procedure. Of course, when $f(x)>0$, because for some reason we appear to be in a moment where people seem to be very adamant about saying stuff like "$\left(\frac1x\right)'=-\frac{1}{x^2}$ holds only if $x\ne 0$".

Answer (score 1):

A generalized power rule is
$$(f^g)'=gf^{g-1}\cdot f' + f^g\log f \cdot g'$$

This generalizes the power rule and the exponential rule simultaneously. It is easily obtained by using implicit differentiation. But it is *extremely* easy to remember if you look at the components of the sum: when $g$ is constant, the factor $g'$ vanishes and you recover the familiar power rule for constant exponents; when $f$ is constant, the factor $f'$ vanishes and you recover the familiar exponential rule for constant bases. Knowing those simple rules, you can piece together the rule easily without rederiving it.

In your case, $f(x)=g(x)=\cos x$, so the result is
$$((\cos x)^{\cos x})'=\cos x(\cos x)^{\cos x - 1}(-\sin x) + (\cos x)^{\cos x}\log\cos x(-\sin x)$$
$$=\boxed{-(\cos x)^{\cos x}\cdot \sin x\cdot(1 + \log\cos x)}$$

Implicitly, this is defined where everything makes sense ($\cos x > 0$, e.g.).

Answer (score 1):

For any function of the type $u(x) ^{v(x)} $, use the logarithmic rule

ie, let $y =u^v$

$\implies ln(y) = vln(u) $

Differentiate wrt x

$\frac{dy}{dx} \frac 1y = v'ln(u) +\frac vu u'$

$\frac{dy}{dx} =y\big(v'ln(u) +\frac vu u'\big) $

For $ cos(x)^{cos(x)} $

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \small cos(x)^{cos(x)} (-sin(x)ln(cos(x)) - sin(x) ) $

Answer (score 0):

So $\cos(x)^{\cos(x)}=e^{\cos(x)ln(\cos(x))}$ and $$\frac{d}{dx} e^{\cos(x)ln(\cos(x))}=e^{\cos(x)ln(\cos(x)} \cdot (-\sin(x) ln(\cos(x))+ -\sin(x)=\cos(x)^{\cos(x)} \cdot -\sin(x) ln(\cos(x))-\sin(x)$$